# How to set indentation style substatement-open offset parameter from .dir-locals.el?

Tags: indentation, cc-mode, directory-local-variables

Within CC mode, for C and C++ files inside a directory, I'd like to have the open braces following a case/do/for/if/while not indented, whatever the style is and without having to change anything in .emacs (in particular creating a global new style).

I've found I have to set [substatement-open](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Syntactic-Symbols.html#Syntactic-Symbols) to 0 in [c-offsets-alist](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/c_002doffsets_002dalist.html) for the buffer.

In .dir-locals.el, I've tried to modify [c-offsets-alist](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/c_002doffsets_002dalist.html), either directly:

```
((nil . ((eval . (add-to-list 'c-offsets-alist '(substatement-open . 0))))))
```

Or by using [c-set-offset](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/c_002doffsets_002dalist.html):

```
((nil . ((eval . (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0)))))
```

Then I've tried to use [c-file-offsets](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/File-Styles.html#File-Styles), still in .dir-locals.el:

```
((nil . ((c-file-offsets . ((substatement-open . 0))))))
```

But none seems to work.

How I can set substatement-open to 0 from .dir-locals.el for C and C++ mode ?

Comment: I just tried your third option and it worked perfectly. Are you accessing these files via TRAMP? By default Emacs doesn't check for a .dir-locals.el file when loading files with TRAMP. Barring that, try this with `emacs -Q`; perhaps there's something wrong with your configuration.

Comment: third option did not work for me as well, just like others

Comment: @DraifKroneg The third option seems to be working for me after a correction: the "body" after `nil` without extra parens and the dot, like this: `((nil (c-file-offsets . ((substatement-open . 0)))))`

Comment: @imz phils wrote: That's not a "correction" -- it's identical. Lists are made out of chains of cons cells, such that `(foo bar)` and `(foo . (bar))` are the same thing. The former is shorthand for the latter. The explicit dotted notation is recommended for `.dir-locals.el` mode and variable specifications, because it's generally clearer (in Emacs 27.1 the add-dir-local-variable command was updated so that it generated this format).